# Text storage of a mini diary

Tags: android, storage

I will do a mini diary project. What is your wishes about the storage? Can I use Android's Note?I will show a photo and a text below of the photo .So,how to store this texts?

Comment: SharedPreferences, to File, SQLite Database

Comment: Depends how much text you are working with, but as the app grows an SQLite database would probably be best and is easy to implement.

Comment: I also use photos.So SQLite database is best for me , isn't it?

Comment: Here is a simple example of a Diary App, all you would need to do is adjust the layout to accomodate an ImageView and have the SQLite Database store the image URI (i wouldn't store the images themselves in the database) --->>> http://www.example8.com/node/view/id/84669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `sqlite` for your requirement. Since in an `sqlite` table you have multiple entries, you can store both your image data and  your text in the same row.

Now the challenge here is how to store images in sqlite?

The solution for this is you can convert your image to byte array and byte array to string. This string can be stored as text in sqlite table and from this string you can retrieve back the byte array and from the byte array your image.

Code to convert an image to byte array:

```
public static byte[] drawableToByteArray(Drawable d) {

    if (d != null) {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] byteData = baos.toByteArray();

        return byteData;
    } else
        return null;

}
```

The byte array that the above function returns you need to convert it to string and store it in the database.

Your sqlite table should be created as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Your_table ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE, someOtherField TEXT, pictureData TEXT);
```

After retrieving data from sqlite, convert your string to byte array and the code to convert byte array to bitmap is given below:

```
public static Drawable byteToDrawable(byte[] data) {

    if (data == null)
        return null;
    else
        return new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length));
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zax. I have a little question. My image type is ImageView.In your methods how can I use it like image?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to develope mini diary project by using SQLite Database.Proper way to fetch and store record(both text and Image).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

refer the above link for basic reference.